# What is the correct word form for telecommunications applications?

Tags: word-request

I cannot find the right, generic term for all the applications and software used for making online calls (i.e. Skype, Zoom, Facetime, Jitsi, etc.).

I found such word collocations as *telecommunications application*, *online call software* and *videotelephony software*.

What would be the best form for the technically untutored English-speaker's ear?

The context - a manual helping to set up the hardware for making video conference calls.

Comment: In this context, *video conference software*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video conferencing software and hardware or solutions

[video conferencing](https://www.videoconferencingaustralia.com.au/web-based-vs-room-based-video-conferencing/)

"What is Room-based **Video Conferencing**?
Room-based video conferencing solutions are usually hardware solutions that are installed, fixed and configured in your boardrooms or meeting rooms.

Room-based video conferencing comprises of an endpoint unit, which communicates over the standards based protocol, H.323, for communication across IP networks. This means that your unit would be compatible to communicate with most other video conferencing solutions on the same protocol."

[Long live Australia. They got it!]